# Can I connect my Philips sound system to my Samsung tablet?

Tags: power, sound, energy, short-circuit, system

I have a [Philips SPA 4310/10 Sound System](http://www.foresoon.com.hk/userfiles/spa4310_10_pss_eng-1.jpg) and I want to connect via 3.5mm jack to my [10" Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 P5200](http://m.digitaltrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/GalaxyTab3-10-01.jpg) to listen some music.

Am I at risk of short-circuiting the tablet? Or will everything work fine, giving that the Sound System gets 220V power.

Comment: I assume by "connect to" you mean through a 3.5mm (or other) audio connector, in which case there is no problem.

Comment: Yes, of course, 3.5mm jack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean connecting your tablet via a 3.5mm jack, through headphone cable to the input on your speaker system, then yes, everything will work fine. The speaker system, as with most, is designed to take a low level input from audio devices such as PCs, laptops and mobile devices. You won't have any issues.

The 220V "power" you state is the voltage the device requires from the mains to operate, but this is not the voltage across the audio input, and will be on a separate, isolated loop to provide amplification to the input audio signal.

Comment: Yes, connect it via 3.5mm jack. Thanks, that answers my question.